# How can I allow users to edit their profiles in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I have a model in models.py like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    Birthday = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    course = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
```

I want to allow my users to make edits, so I made a function like this in my views.py:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profil = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        profil.phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
        profil.Birthday = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
        profil.city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
        profil.school = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
        profil.course = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
        
        profil.save()
        
        return redirect('profile')  
 
    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html')
```

My template is:

```
<form action="." method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}    
        Phone Number:
        <input type="text" name="phone_number" value="{{  profil.phone_number }}" /><br />
        Birthday:
        <input type="text" name="Birthday" value="{{  profil.Birthday }}" /><br />
    
        city:
        <input type="text" name="city" value="{{  profil.city }}" /><br />
        school:
        <input type="text" name="school" value="{{  profil.school }}" /><br />
    
        course:
        <input type="text" name="course" value="{{  profil.course }}" /><br />
       
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="save" />
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="cancel" />
        <br/>
    </form>
```

I do not know why, but after filling the form I get an error saying page not found. And if I check the existing user profile nothing got updated. Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an error

```
profil = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
profil.phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
```

you get an `UserProfile` object and then instead of saving `str` into `phone_number` you try to save an object `models.CharField`.
use `ModelForm` to achieve what you need.

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

then in your view you can use:

```
userprofile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST if request.POST else None, instance = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user))
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()     
        return redirect('profile')  

return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', context={'userprofile_form': userprofile_form)
```

and in html use:

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}    
    Phone Number: {{ userprofile_form.phone_number }}
    Birthday: {{ userprofile_form.Birthday }}
    city: {{ userprofile_form.city }}
    school: {{ userprofile_form.school }}
    course: {{ userprofile_form.course }}           
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="save" />
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="cancel" />
    <br/>
</form>
```

or just

```
 <form action="." method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}    
     {{ userprofile_form }}           
     <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="save" />
     <input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="cancel" />
     <br/>
 </form>
```

if you want to use upload files, don't forget to put your files into form you can do it
`UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user))`
and in html you need to put `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="...">`

Comment: Thank you so much it works i am able to make users change thier profile. But in the actual model there is an image field so when i tried changing the image or uploading new it does not save it

Comment: modified answer

Answer (score 1):

Reproduce these steps, you might need slight modifications:

**1. Create a UserEditForm**

in forms.py

```
from .models import UserProfile
from django.forms import ModelForm

class UserEditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__' # or ['phone_number', 'Birthday', 'city', 'only_fields_you_want_to_edit']
```

**2. Create a View:**

in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
from .models import UserProfile
from .forms import UserEditForm

def userEdit(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=user_id)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = UserEditForm(initial=model_to_dict(user))
        return render(request, 'yourapp/useredit_form.html', {'form':form)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = UserEditForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_profile', kwargs={'uid':user.id}))
        else:
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('some_fail_loc'))
```

**3. Create template**

in yourapp/useredit_form.html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**4. Set a URL:**

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('edit_user/<int:user_id>/', views.userEdit, name='user_edit'),
]
```

Now try visiting `yourapp.com/edit_user/1`. You are good to go. :D